# Date give or take a number of days with Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to find a crossover between 2 data sets that have crossovers entries for the same job. Meaning, **SOMETIMES** when a job is done it will have an ID and date entered within both data sets.

Here's the kicker though, the dates given are based on different criteria. In one data set it is the completion date, in the other it is the order date. For the most part, these are the same or within a day or two of each other.

Note: This is in the form of an INNER JOIN query and I currently only have exact date crossovers.

Comment: Access have datediff() function. You can use it to create a join where date difference is within X days.

Comment: Please show some SQL code, table structure and data sample. It is not possible to help you without it

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATEFIFF() function and to get the exact date combine it with OR

Comment: An answer needs a little more than this. If thought of as a hint only, post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Select 
    Table1.*,
    Table2.*
From
    Table1,
    Table2
Where
    Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    And
    Abs(DateDiff("d", Table1.TheDateField, Table2.TheOtherDateField)) < 2
```